# Road not vertically following curve, but following horizontaly

Tags: bezier-curves

The thing on the screenshot is a inside of a terrain (and blue is sea level) and that road shouldn't be there, the curve is using the shrinkwrap to follow the terrain and that's working fine as you can see, the road is following the terrain correctly left/right and that's also ok, but for some reason the road just doesn't want to go upwards and follow the curve vertically. I subdivided the road section a bunch of times, but that didn't do anything.

Another important thing is that when I created the curve it did actually kind of bend the road upwards, but not nearly enough, so I went into the object data section of Nurbs object (the window opened on the screenshot) to try to improve it, I pressed "2D" and that's when the road got flat like this, ever since that I can't get it to change vertically no matter what I press.

[image]

Comment: Yep needs to be a 3D curve. How are you shrinkwrapping? Suggest moving curve such that it is totally above the terrain and projecting down onto from above.

Comment: The curve is alright, maybe it's not the best screenshot, but it can be seen, it is moving along the terrain fine, but the road mesh just doesn't want to follow it vertically, it only follows it horizontally. Maybe I haven't applied the shrinkwap modifier to the correct object or is there a certain order of modifiers where the shrink needs to be? I always put it at the end, tried moving it up, but nothing.